# How can I create class properties from a for loop going through object keys?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a class that has it's properties generated from a for loop going over object keys as shown below:

e.g. I want to create:

```
// Result I'm hoping for..
class MyClass {
  public earth = 'element'
  public fire = 'element'
  public wind = 'element'
}

// What I'm trying to do..
let object = {
     earth: 'stone',
     fire: 'flame',
     wind:  'air'
}

class MyClass {
   constructor(object) {
       for (let key in object) { 
         console.log(key);
         this.${key} = 'element';
       }
   }
}

let dynamicPropClass = new MyClass(object);
```

How can I create class properties based on a object key names in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allow dynamic properties on a class you need to define an index signature like this:

```
class MyClass {
   [key: string]: any;

   constructor(object) {
       for (let key in object) {          
         this[key] = 'element';
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! : )

Comment: @Jonathan002 You are welcome! :) If this answers your question, could you please mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: Yea I was, it didn't let me mark it as correct for another min.